# Grouping MySQL result with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a PHP page which does a query in mysql, but I have repeatable results and I want to join them. I want this to be the outcome:

```
Client Type Analysis
  1      1     0001
               0002
         2     0010

  2      1     1110
```

But my actual outcome is this:

```
 Client Type Analysis
  1      1     0001
         1     0002
         2     0010

  2      1     1110
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
$query = mysqli_query( $db, 'SELECT * FROM laudos ORDER BY cliente, tipo');
$cli = array();

while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $cli[$row['cliente']][] = $row;
}
?>

<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
<tr>
    <td>Cliente</td>
    <td>Tipo</td>
    <td>Análises</td>
</tr>
<?php 
    foreach($cli as $cliente => $values){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $cliente; ?></td>
    <?php foreach($values as $resul) { ?>
    <tr>            
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $resul['tipo'];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option SELECTED>Escolha um laudo</option>
                <option><?php echo $resul['legisla'].'-'.$resul['numero'];}?></option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Edit: I want to group by column `Type`

Comment: `I want to join it`, you have to explain what are you trying to do. Now we can't help you.

Comment: so, either you want to join or want to remove duplicates? please be more specific.

Comment: Do want to join table to itself?

Comment: Usually you use joins to select some data out of two or more tables. In your case, I see only one.

Answer (score -1):

For joining you tables you need two or more tables in aggregation. It can be joined 1:N or N:N,

For example:

- Table: person

  - columns: TaxID, name, lastname, phoneid

person can have more phones

- table: phones
- columns: phoneId,phone type,phoneNumber